# CSS float: centered workaround possible?

Tags: css, css-float, center

I have a tagcloud in wich the tags (in Divs) should float centered. There is no float: center so I'm looking for a clean solution. My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="tagcloud">
  <div class="tag">Tag 1</div>
  <div class="tag">Tag 2</div>
  <div class="tag">Tag 3</div>
  <div class="tag">Tag 4</div>
</div>
```

The Divs should float with space to both sides (centered). I'm not sure how to explain this any better. Any ideas?

thanks!

**update**
The .tag divs must have a flexible width so that varying content fits into them.

Also it should be possible to have several tags in one line (if they are short enough)

My CSS so far:

```
.tag {
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  float: left;
  margin: auto; }
  .tag img {
    border-right: 1px solid #fff;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    vertical-align: top; }
  .tag a {
    font: bold 10px Verdana;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
    height: 16px;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000; }

#tagcloud {
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-align: center; }
  #tag_box #tagcloud .tag {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto; }
```

My HTML:

```
            <div id='tagcloud'>
              <div class='tag' id='tag_1004'>
                <img alt="Tag_22x17" src="/images/tag_22x17.png?1245428671" />
                <span class='name'><a href="/tags/design">design</a></span>
              </div>
              <div class='tag' id='tag_1005'>
                <img alt="Tag_22x17" src="/images/tag_22x17.png?1245428671" />

                <span class='name'><a href="/tags/degeneration">degeneration</a></span>
              </div>
              <div class='tag' id='tag_1006'>
                <img alt="Tag_22x17" src="/images/tag_22x17.png?1245428671" />
                <span class='name'><a href="/tags/deggendorf">deggendorf</a></span>
              </div>
              <div class='tag' id='tag_1007'>
                <img alt="Tag_22x17" src="/images/tag_22x17.png?1245428671" />

                <span class='name'><a href="/tags/hamburg">hamburg</a></span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you set the #tagcloud and .tag styles to the same width you could then just align the text center.

```
#tagcloud, .tag {
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

another option would be as follows:

```
#tagcloud {
  width:100px;
  text-align:center;
}

.tag {
  display:inline;
}
```

Comment: not working, because the width of .tag has to be flexible (depends on content) and also if there is enough space several tags should appear in one line

Comment: the only option then would be to text-align center on the tagcloud but you then have to display:inline for the tags.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this might help?

```
.tag
{
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:100px;
}
```

Comment: Please tell me why this should get a downvote? It's an acceptable way to center a div.

Comment: you would need to give a width to the tag class to use margin auto

Comment: thanks for the reply (I didn't give you a downvote), but this solution isn't working (first thing I tried). Also #tagcloud { text-align: center; } isn't working.

Comment: I can't give a width to the tag-class, because I don't know how wide it is (depends on the content).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
.tag
{
text-align:center;
display:inline;
}

#tagcloud{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It work on My computer

```
   <style>
.tag {
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  display:inline;
  margin: auto; }



  .tag img {
  }


  .tag a {
    font: bold 10px Verdana;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    padding: 3px 4px 3px 4px;
    height: 16px;

    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: top;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000; }



#tagcloud {
  margin-top: 7px;
  text-align: center; }



</style>
```